# Get the particular records from an array with a condition

Tags: arraylist

Below is the array from which I need

1. all the spId where isNumber = true
2. all the spId where isSpecial = true

```json
[
    {
        "spId": "1",
        "isNumber": true,
        "isSpecial": true,
        "sportName": "Cricket",
        "ranking": 58,
        "eventnumbers": 666,
        "liveEventCount": 13
    },
    {
        "spId": "5",
        "isNumber": true,
        "isSpecial": false,
        "sportName": "hockey",
        "ranking": 59,
        "eventnumbers": 192,
        "liveEventCount": 15
    },
    {
        "spId": "2",
        "isNumber": false,
        "isSpecial": true,
        "sportName": "football",
        "ranking": 59,
        "eventnumbers": 60,
        "eventCount": 100
    },
    {
        "spId": "23",
        "isNumber": false,
        "isSpecial": false,
        "sportName": "VOLLEY",
        "ranking": 61,
        "eventnumbers": 42,
        "liveEventCount": 4
    }
]
```

I've tried this

```js
var isNumber_expected= isNumber_sp_ids.length;
pm.test(`There are ${isNumber_expected} number sports`, function () {
    pm.expect(sports.filter(sport => sport.isNumber).length).to.equal(isNumber_expected);
});
```

I have to match the spId in the array with all the spIds available SpId array = [1,2,3,4,5,23,34].

Here I'm not getting the correct number

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like filter on boolean, checkout [docs Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

here is usage on your data

```js
const array = [
    {
        "spId": "1",
        "isNumber": true,
        "isSpecial": true,
        "sportName": "Cricket",
        "ranking": 58,
        "eventnumbers": 666,
        "liveEventCount": 13
    },
    {
        "spId": "5",
        "isNumber": true,
        "isSpecial": false,
        "sportName": "hockey",
        "ranking": 59,
        "eventnumbers": 192,
        "liveEventCount": 15
    },
    {
        "spId": "2",
        "isNumber": false,
        "isSpecial": true,
        "sportName": "football",
        "ranking": 59,
        "eventnumbers": 60,
        "eventCount": 100
    },
    {
        "spId": "23",
        "isNumber": false,
        "isSpecial": false,
        "sportName": "VOLLEY",
        "ranking": 61,
        "eventnumbers": 42,
        "liveEventCount": 4
    }
];

const isNumber_sp_ids = array.filter(item => item.isNumber);
const isSpecial_sp_ids = array.filter(item => item.isSpecial);

console.log(`There are ${isNumber_sp_ids.length} number sports [${isNumber_sp_ids.map(item => item.spId)}]`);
console.log(`There are ${isSpecial_sp_ids.length} special sports [${isSpecial_sp_ids.map(item => item.spId)}]`);
```